# When/how does the Quick Learner merit work?

Tags: all-flesh-must-be-eaten, unisystem

The quick learner merit (Quick Learner 3-point Mental Quality) states that:

> As a result, when the character starts learning a new regular skill he
>   gains one level or speciality free up to level five. For  levels
>   higher than five or for special skills reduce the cost by one point
>   for the next level.

I find this merit a bit confusing. **How does it work?**

1. Does this quality work: a.) only AFTER char creation or b.) also during char creation?
2. Am I correct that I get 1 additional skill or one speciality IN TOTAL and then after lvl 5 a point cost decrease?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a quality that takes place only after character creation.  It specifies **new** regular skills, and this is defined in character creation on page 51 as skills gained after character creation, during the course of play.  This merit decreases the steep (6 xp) cost of gaining new skills during play.  Compare that cost against the cost of learning skills during character creation (5 points for level 5 during character creation).

There is a Merit in the book "One of the Living" (page 16) that does apply to character creation, the Cloistered quality.  This quality specifies in its text that it impacts characters during creation.

Comment: This would mean then that those who do not focus on just 2-3 skills at char creation get a "penalty" for having that quality. As they already by then got all skills they probably will need (if they for example take 20 skills). Or am I mistaken there?

Comment: I don't think so, but I can see it like that.  I believe that is why the point reduction exists for higher level skills, as it still provides benefit for more (and more varied) skilled characters.

Comment: Btw just stumbled upon: Page 51 in the revised edition rulebook. "Learning new skills" after char creation. So explicitely stated that learning "new skills" is afterwards.

Comment: I'll include that in the answer update that I'm going to do tonight.  I've been looking more into this question over the past few days.

Comment: did you update the answer?