# Aside from Quick Learner are there other qualities that take effects only AFTER character creation?

Tags: all-flesh-must-be-eaten

As can be seen here:
[When/how does the Quick Learner merit work?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/67030/when-how-does-the-quick-learner-merit-work)
The quick learner positive quality comes into effect only AFTER character creation.
Are there any other qualities for which this is the case? OR is this the only one?
(With effect I mean they have effects on costs,.... but not on character creation costs but only for costs afterwards).

Comment: I answered to the best that I understand your question.  Does this answer fit what you're intending to ask, or is the question different than I'm understanding?

Comment: Ah nope. what I meant is most of the merits have effects or at least fluff that is in action already at char creation (you are hard to kill and were so even before becoming a PC as example). But quick learner explicitely is only active AFTER char creation as its rules say that it affects only skills after char creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest result I can find is **Old Soul** because it only affects untrained skills, which come only after character creation.  Even if you started unskilled and learn it, you lose the Quality's bonus so things after the creation change the way it functions instead of being static throughout (IE -3 on Roll-Type-X, even if you have a +10)

Comment: hmmm the same is then also true for additional essence qualities or am I mistaken?

Comment: From what I've seen, it's the only one where the effect can change dynamically instead of being implicit.

Answer (score 1):

All merits that I have found (with the exception of Cloistered and Bilingual (Both from "One of the Living", p 16) ) take effect after character creation, modifying your rolls, how the DM presents information or what options are available to you.